# Is there a way to match URLs regardless query parameters or localised subdomains

Tags: javascript, regex, url

For a bookmarking functionality I'm storing URLs in a database. When the user visits this URL the window.location.href gets compared to the stored URLs in the database, to check if it's bookmarked or not.

The problem is, the same webpage can have different URLs because of the query parameters or localised subdomains.

For example I want to be able to recognise that all the following links are the same:

Example 1: `"www.example.com/about?referalId=1234"`
Example 2: `"www.example.com/about?userAuth=1"`
Example 3: `"fr.example.com/about"`

I'm aware that `location.href.split("?")[0];` will remove all parameters, but this won't work for all webpages as for example `"youtube.com/watch?v=123456"` won't work if the query parameter was removed.

What is the best practice in this case? any library that does that? 
And how do i ignore the subdomain 'fr.' in my comparison. Thanks a lot

Comment: Use the properties of [location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) to isolate the relevant parts.

Comment: Regex can break things down for you, but your problem is semantic. You will have to define what parameters and subdomains are important for which URLs, or give users the ability to do it themselves.